# How to append np.arrays to a file and use them for plotting purposes later

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, file, numpy, save

I'm creating multiple np.arrays of the shape (1,2) inside a for-loop. The arrays contain the x- and the y-coordinates of some positions. In each iteration I overwrite these arrays. I want to store these arrays inside a file, so that I can use them later on to make plots. I don't care, if the file is readable for humans.

For now I only tried it for two (1,2) arrays, but it is really important, that I can store an arbitrary number of arrays in the file. 
I tried writing the arrays to a .txt file with `filename.write('{}\n'.format(arr))`, but I failed to reuse them for plotting. Also I don't see yet how I will be able to write multiple arrays to the file like this.

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[-1, 0], [1, 0]])
# write to a .txt file:
with open('file.dat', 'w+') as f:
    f.write('{}\t{}\n'.format(arr[0], arr[1]))
    for i in range(3):
        arr = arr + 2
        f.write('{}\t{}\n'.format(arr[0], arr[1]))
```

The file looks like this:

```
[2 3]   [4 3]
[5 6]   [7 6]
[8 9]   [10  9]
```

With this code I get one column of vectors on the left and one column of vectors on the right. 
What I want to do now is to plot `arr[0][0]` against `arr[0][1]` for every vector in the first column and the same for the second column of vectors. So I want to load this information from the file and get again arrays.
Please keep in mind, that this example only shows my problem for two (1,2) arrays, but I need to be able to do the same for an arbitrary amount of vectors i.e. it should also work for `arr = np.array([[-1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 2])` and even more vectors .

Comment: Your `arr` is (2,2) shape.  The form you write to the file: "[2 3]  [4 3]" is hard to parse.  A simple `csv` layout is better: "2, 3, 4, 3".

Comment: Why don't you collect these arrays in a list, and then make a larger array from that list?  You know how to `append` values to a list in a `for` loop, don't you?

Comment: @hpaulj Yes my example `arr` is (2,2), but like I said, I want to write it as separate (1,2) arrays or in whatever shape needed so that I can make my desired plots from the data. What do you mean by "a simple csv layout"? If I put the arrays in a list I would have to keep this huge list through the whole for loop, that's the reason why I want to save my data externally.

Answer (score 0):

Use `numpy.savez` or `numpy.savez_compressed` to save one or multiple arrays (they can have different data types and shapes) into a file.
 Later, you can restore them using `numpy.load`

e.g:

```py
my_arrays = [ np.ones([2, 2])*k for k in range(0, 4) ]
np.savez('myfile.npz', *my_arrays)

# Now restore it back
my_arrays = list(np.load('myfile.npz').values())
```